# What is wrong with my POM? "Resolving expression..detected recursive expression cycle"

Tags: java, maven

So I have some TestNG SuiteXML files containing runtime params like so:-

```
 <!--SERVER AND TARGET PARAMS-->
    <parameter name="environment" value="${environment}"/>
    <parameter name="port" value="${port}"/>
```

and my POM looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>co.uk.multicom.test.project</groupId>
<artifactId>fab-handler-automation</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <sl4j.version>1.7.7</sl4j.version>
    <suiteFile>${suiteFile}</suiteFile>
    <environment>${environment}</environment>
    <port>${port}</port>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory</name>
                        <value>org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>user.language</name>
                        <value>en</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
                <!--<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>-->
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <environment>${environment}</environment>
                    <port>${port}</port>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>parallel</name>
                        <value>methods</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>threadCount</name>
                        <value>1</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
                        <value>1</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- pom.xml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My error is:

```
[ERROR]     Resolving expression: '${environment}': Detected the following recursive expression cycle in 'environment': [environment] -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Resolving expression: '${port}': Detected the following recursive expression cycle in 'port': [port] -> [Help 2]
```

Am I being stupid? Probably, I am only a tester after all and have a very small brain. Can anyone help me troubleshoot?  Does my POM look squiffy?

It will not download my required jars to the local .m2 until I can fix it - I have tried blowing away .m2 and doing mvn install etc....no joy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your errors come from this part:

```
<properties>
    <sl4j.version>1.7.7</sl4j.version>
    <suiteFile>${suiteFile}</suiteFile>
    <environment>${environment}</environment>
    <port>${port}</port>
</properties>
```

When you use *${port}* Maven looks for the value in `<port>X</port>` which here X=${port} and so on... So that's why you get a recursive issue here

Comment: this makes sense, thank you - I am passing these as switches from Jenkins so if I fail to pass locally then the error occurs.  I can actually just comment them out for now as I'm debugging locally on my home pc.  If you see a more general problem with the POM structure, any help much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure because I only have time for a quick look, but defining a property and then assigning that property to itself is what I think your doing and is what causes the error.

Can't you just use ${suiteFile} in your pom without defining it in your `<properties></properties>`?

Or can you use another property name in the pom?
for example:

```
 <properties>
        <suiteFile1>${suiteFile}</suiteFile>
        <environment1>${environment}</environment>
        <port1>${port}</port>
    </properties>
```

and use those further down in your pom?

Answer (score 0):

may be you can read the maven documentation , it will tell us not support format which you writed. 
https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties

Perhaps try the following way :

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <os>
                <family>mac</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
             <suiteFile>${suiteFile}</suiteFile>
             <environment>${environment}</environment>
             <port>${port}</port>
        </properties>
   </profile>
</profiles>
```

and execute:

```
clean package -pl ${project_name} -am -Denv=prod -DskipTests=true
```

**Note:** ${project_name} is your project name

I may be wrong to describe, you can try it

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same issue today. What was more intriguing was that it was after I had executed the same project successfully a few minutes before. Turns out the Build configuration had error where the command (clean package etc) was written in profile instead.
Silly mistake but caused me to spend some time and that reason why it worked earlier was because I entered the command manually rather than using the saved build configuration.